# Open Connection to database, How to check if still existing?

Tags: c#

I open connection to database in the biginig of my program (one time)

after 5 minute the server shut down.

how I can catch this problem ?

I am not open connection befor any query

thank's

Comment: What kind of database? What library do you use to connect to it?

Comment: What kind of program? What version of .NET?

Answer (score 2):

In general you shouldn't keep the connection open, but keep the connection in the pool. If the connection is broken, any command you try to execute on it will throw an exception and you can handle the problem and attempt to reconnect.

Comment: Yuriy is correct.  Instead of opening the connection when your program starts (and presumably closing it when your program ends), you should connect, execute the query, and then disconnect each time you run a query.  If the server goes down while your program is running, either the connection attempt or (very rarely because of timing issues) the query execution will throw an exception, which your program can catch.

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldnt keep you connection open. But if the connection has been open for some time its always prudent to check if the conneciton is still active.

Sqlconnection has a connection state property, and also catch sqlexceptions so you know that the problem is db related.